# How to list all the empty directories using windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a windows batch file which lists all the empty sub-directories present under the user specified root directory.

Can anybody help regarding the same?

Comment: Check this discussion: ["How to list empty directories"](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.msdos.batch.nt/browse_thread/thread/eec723b8096005b5/6416b835f5fca5d1?pli=1)

Comment: I was found that there is a tools called [MarkEmptyDirs](https://code.google.com/p/markemptydirs/).  Here is the sample usage syntax: MarkEmptyDirs.exe -d -v C:\Some\Dir

Answer (score 18):

```
@echo off
for /d /r %1 %%A in (.) do (
  dir /a /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul || echo %%~fA
)
```

The above solution ignores Hidden folders. I've also been told that using both /D and /R options with FOR is bugged, though I've never had a problem with it.

---

```
@echo off
dir /a /b %1 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul || echo %%~fA
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in ('dir /s /ad /b %1') do (
  dir /a /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul || echo %%~fA
)
```

The 2nd solution that avoids FOR /D /R  will include Hidden folders. But I believe it can fail if folder names contain Unicode.

Comment: What's [dir /a /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul] this mean?  I don't understand why you tried to find out the "^" character?

Comment: @WillHuang - I'm not looking for the `^` character, it is actually a primitive regular expression that will match any line. The `^` character represents the beginning of a line. The `||` operator conditionally executes the `echo %%~fA` only if the FINDSTR failed, which is when there were no lines found, meaning the directory is empty.

Comment: Note that this won't list directories that contain only empty subdirectories, so after removing found empty directories there might appear new ones.