# Shell script - Linux - list empty directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to list all empty directories below the directory specified in the input parameter using a shell script, but all I can find is command for listing empty directories in the current directory only. Please help.

For example:
I have:

```
Documents
   directory 1 (the empty directory)
   directory 2
      Subdirectory 1
      Subdirectory 2 (where I have my shell script, getemptydir.sh)
```

So when I type `./getemptydir.sh` Documents, I would want it to print out `directory 1`

Comment: Already answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884729/how-to-list-all-the-empty-directories-using-windows-batch-file

Comment: @CorbinMc that's windows, question is linux. batch-file tag is inaccurate

Comment: That's still not clear. What are actual names of the directories, and what is a subdirectory of what? Are they called `Documents directory 1`, `Documents`, `directory 1`, just `1`, etc.? You say `./getemptydir.sh Document` but nowhere do you mention a directory called just `Document`

Comment: Sorry for not being so clear and I had a mistype. My script which I want to run to solve this  I called it getemptydir.sh.
So the directories are like this:Home/Documents. In Documents there are 2 folders: bds and fol (fol is empty). In bds there are 2 folders: bds 1 and bds2 (my script is in bds2). So I want to know when I run my script from the folder bds2, I enter Documents as my parameter for the script ( which is ./getemptydir.sh Documents), it should print out ./fol because it is an empty directory.

Comment: the point is that when someone run the script file, it should be able to print out the empty directories that are in the input directory specified in the parameter

Comment: the problem is that you're telling it to look for a directory called Documents in the current directory, which is bds2, and Documents is not inside bds2. So you have some choices - run the script from the Home directory, change the script to look in the Home directory regardless of where it's run from, pass a full path to the script. I've edited my answer to gives examples of these approaches

Comment: by `Home` do you mean the user's home directory, and if so do you want your script to always look in the user's home directory rather than any arbitrary directory you may pass it? Or is there actually a directory called `Home`

Comment: `Home` was just an example, I would want to have any directory I may pass it in the script file and it should work (like to check that directory out and find the empty directories inside there)

Comment: If you are currently in directory `bds2` and you pass `Documents` as a parameter, you mean a directory called `Documents` inside the current directory `bds2`. If you want to run it on a directory outside the current one, you need to give it a relative path (e.g. `../../Documents`) or an absolute path (e.g. `/Users/you/Documents`, or a shortcut like `~/Documents`). Otherwise the script won't know where you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
#!/bin/sh
find "$1" -type d -empty
```

This script will run relative to the current directory. If you're in `bds2` and pass it `Documents` it will look for a directory in `bds2` called `Documents`. But you can pass it a relative or absolute path to your directory and it will work, e.g.

```
$ ./getemptydir.sh ../../Documents
$ ./getemptydir.sh ~/Documents
$ ./getemptydir.sh /Users/xyz/Documents
```

etc.

or from the Home directory, you would run

```
$ Documents/bds/bds2/getemptydir.sh Documents
```

If you wanted the script to always look in your home directory, you could include that in the script, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
find "$HOME/$1" -type d -empty
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but I got an error, let me try to be more specific:
I have:
Documents
   directory 1 (the empty directory)
   directory 2
      Subdirectory 1
      Subdirectory 2 (where I have my batch file)

So when I typed in ./getemptydir.sh Document, I would want it to print out the directory 1

Comment: find: `Documents': No such file or directory
That is the error I got

Comment: well, if your script is nested inside your Documents directory you'll need to do `./getemptydir.sh ..` or `./getemptydir.sh ../..` depending on how deep it is - I still haven't quite got my head around your directory structure

Comment: I disagree. The answer does answer the original question, but the author's comments *here* show that the author is not invoking the script correctly

Comment: You should use `"$1"` (or even `"$@"`) in the argument to `find` in the first option.  Is there a reason not to use `"$HOME"` in place of `/whatever/Home`?  It tends to be a better representation of the home directory.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's unlikely that `Home` is actually the user's home directory unless the user is called `Home`, so `$HOME` is likely to be completely wrong, although I will concede that perhaps the author intended Home to mean the user's home directory, in which case, yes `$HOME` would be best

Comment: I mean `"$1"` with double quotes around the value, so that if the name given contains spaces (etc), the value passed to `find` is preserved as a single argument rather than mangled into multiple separate arguments.  On the other point, I think that the `Home/Documents` referred to in a comment is probably a sloppily written variation of `$HOME/Documents` (or `~/Documents` — usually the same place) which is where 'the' `Documents` folder is created by default.

Comment: Ok, so `Home` was just an example. I've tidied up the answer based on the clarifications in the question comments

Comment: @CupawnTae, Thanks so much for the solution, it helps! I am just wondering, is there any directory above HOME?

Comment: If you mean `$HOME`, then yes, usually `$HOME` is something like `/Users/username` - you can just do `echo $HOME` to see the current value. The directory above that would be `/Users` - which is also `$HOME/..`