# DIR Command in Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, dir

How do I use the DIR command to list all directories, including subdirectories, that contain no files?  I've researched this at length and can only find how to DELETE the specified directories, but not actually list them.  Can anyone help?  Is there a better way other than the DIR command?

Comment: Do you have the command that you would use to delete?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884729/how-to-list-all-the-empty-directories-using-windows-batch-file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831286/how-to-delete-empty-folders-using-windows-command-prompt

Comment: Thanks for the info gordatron...  Did you see my link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the Powerscript answer on the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19239549/33499) to display instead of delete like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse . | where { $_.PSISContainer -and @( $_ | Get-ChildItem ).Count -eq 0 } | Select-Object -Property FullName
```