# Select ONLY folders that contain files

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I currently retrieve the folder structure and create a database with each folder contained in the Parent folder. The problem is, when there is a folder that does not contain any files, it falls over.

```
INSERT INTO DBName
EXECUTE XP_CMDSHELL 'dir \\FAS-RBGFS01\costec\FTP\ /b'
```

This brings back a list of ALL folders regardless if it has data in or not:

```
output
CAD
CEN
CRO
EXC
FRM
IND
LGL
RSK
ZZZ
NULL
```

Folder "CAD" does not contain any files.

How do I only select the folders which contain files/data in them?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @DanBracuk I think it's just SQL (T-SQL w/ SQL Server to be exact).

Comment: Hi Dan Bracuk, I use SQL to import the folder structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve it using `dir` command. Rather you can use a batch script and call that batch script with `XP_CMDSHELL` like below.

Taken from [how-to-list-all-the-empty-directories-using-windows-batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884729/how-to-list-all-the-empty-directories-using-windows-batch-file)

You can have the below script saved in a file named `test.bat`

```
@echo off
dir /a /b %1 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul || echo %%~fA
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in ('dir /s /ad /b %1') do (
  dir /a /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul || echo %%~fA
)
```

Then call it like

```
INSERT INTO DBName
EXECUTE XP_CMDSHELL 'test.bat \\FAS-RBGFS01\costec\FTP\'
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, I have created the .bat file as requested and executed the script provided but the following error gets imported to my DBName table : 

'test.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Appologies, I have updated the execution script provided to point to the location of the .bat file and it now imports the folders which does not contain any files. How can I now achive the opposite? I want to select the folders which does contain files and exclude the folders which does not contain files.

Comment: I have imported the folders (using your script) into a TEMP table and deleted from DBName where that record exist in the TEMP table. This then only leaves the folders in DBName which contains files.

Your advise really helped me a lot. Thank You!