# How does findstr "^" equate to an empty directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, directory, is-empty

Batch files in Windows can be confusing at the best of times. How does

```
  findstr "^"
```

equate to finding an empty folder, when ^ means the start of the line?

```
for /d /r %1 %%A in (.) do (
  dir /ad /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul || echo %%~fA
)
```

taken from [dbenham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884729/how-to-list-all-the-empty-directories-using-windows-batch-file)

Unless I'm reading this wrong and it's

```
dir /ad /b "%%~fA" 2>nul
```

that finds empty folders.

Comment: The provided link doesn't `dir /ad /B ...` It's just `dir /a /b...` to include also hidden,system attributes. `findstr "^"` will match any line and return no success to the conditional execution operator `||` if there is none.

Answer (score 3):

This script will get a list of directories (and their subdirectories), loop through each directory to check for subdirectories, then list only the directory names that did not contain a subdirectory. The original script in the link provided works similarly except that it will only list *completely* empty directories (not containing subdirectories *or* files). Here is a breakdown of each section of code:

---

The `for /d` in your example is getting a recursive list of directories:

```
for /d /r %1 %%A in (.) do ( )
```

- [**for /d**](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) loops through the specified set of directories
- [**for /d /r**](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) tells the `for` loop to recurse into subdirectories
- **%1** is an optional file path specified from the command-line
- **%%A** will return the current directory in each loop
- **in (SET)** specifies the directory set to loop through
- Specifying "**in (.)**" tells `for` to loop through all directories

---

The code inside your `for` loop then checks each directory to see if it's empty*:

```
  dir /ad /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul || echo %%~fA
```

- **[dir /ad /b "PATH"](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)** gets a list of *subdirectories* in the specified path*
- "**[%%~fA](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)**" expands the current directory name to its full path
- **[2>nul](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)** hides any `dir` errors by redirecting STDERR to nul
- **[|](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)** pipes the list of subdirectories found by `dir` into `findstr`
- **[findstr "^"](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)** then checks for a non-empty list of subdirectories
- **[>nul](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)** hides the `findstr` results by redirecting all output to nul
- **[||](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)** runs a command if the previous command failed (no `findstr` results)
- **echo %%~fA** returns the directory name if no sub-directories were found*

---

***Please Note**: as mentioned by *LotPings*, the code you provided will produce different results than in the example you linked to. `dir /a /b` lists all files and directories while `dir /ad /b` lists directories only. This means that your script will list all directories not containing a subdirectory (but that may still contain files). If this was the expected behavior, please disregard this note.

**Edit:** further broke down the above list of commands as suggested by *Ben Voigt*.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're grouping redirection to nul together with `||`.  For `|` it makes some sense because piping is a form of redirection.

Comment: Agreed. It could be confusing or misleading since there was no logical connection between those sections of the command. I'm not sure why I grouped them that way after I broke everything else down either. I have now updated my answer to further clarify this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the piece of this that you're missing is the `||` (logical OR) operation.

It runs the command after it only if the preceding command fails.

Knowing this, it will make sense that `dir /ad /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul` is not looking for empty directories.  It is succeeding when the list generated by `dir` is NOT empty.  It fails when the listing is empty.